# Wordpress MU - Creating a site takes ages

Tags: multisite

I have 2 dedicated servers. I have Wordpress MU on both. When I try to create a site

1. WP MU 1 on server 1 does it in 3-5 seconds
2. WP MU 2 on server 2 does it in 45-50 seconds

What can cause this delay?
How can I debug PHP and MySQL?

PS: Both WP MU are test installations. No plugins activated. Both OS are CentOS.

Comment: Are you using latest version of WordPress?

Comment: Yes for both site.

Comment: Very first step might be using [sql monitor plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/sqlmon/) to check your queries.

Comment: For ubuntu and debian, there is amazing tools which name is easyengine.please try it.

Comment: @Sisir I instsalled. DB looks fast.

Comment: @ahmetlutfu easyengine is for nginx. Mine is Apache.

Comment: Yeah easyengine for nginx.it also has wp-cli for command line management for wordpress.it is super easy.i recommend nginx.

Comment: @ahmetlutfu using nginx is not an option.